# App development: easiest way to get a phones current location

Tags: android, geolocation

I have reviewed the docs for google's geolocation API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#auth

but it asks for inputs which I am not sure how one would know before making the request.  Does anyone have an example of making such a call.  Usually all I need is one to look at and then I am running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google Play Service to detect device current location.

You have to setup Google Play Service SDK first.

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Then follow the location tutorial.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

You will have to ask for the location permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```